# Google Places API wnd Windows 8 Metro Style App

Tags: google-maps-api-3, microsoft-metro, javascript-injection

I am developing a Metro style app and need access to the Google Places API (I have an app key). Windows 8 prevents Java script injections unless wrapped in a

```
 MSApp.executeLocalUnsafeFunction( function () { 
      document.write('…etc');
 });
```

Because of this, `maps.googleapis.com/maps/js` fails to load.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the errors you are getting?

Comment: No. There are no errors, the script silently fails to load (due to the script injection).

Comment: The name of the Function is MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction! You have wrote MSapp.executeLocalUnsafeFunction

Answer (score 0):

Use the [asynchronous loader](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#asynch). It doesn't use `document.write`.

Comment: Tried it. the 'callback' never executes. 'google' is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help your issue, but I kept getting a JavaScript error along the lines of "google undefined." I wrote this tutorial about using the Google Maps API with Windows 8, http://www.creepyed.com/2012/11/how-to-use-the-google-maps-api-on-windows-8/. It has to do with being able to load an external script in Windows 8, which it won't do for the Visual Studio templates.

I hope this helps!